# Slow to get max and min values related to parameters of each row

Tags: mysql, max

I need to get certain tracked data, including a couple of max and mins. I already have a horrible way to do it below, but as you know this is REALLY slow because i'm using subqueries and the table has a couple of thousands of rows. Specifically I need to get a different MAX values per row, depending on the type_dev of the current row. with 24000 records it becomes unusable, and I think is even slower when I try with MAX clauses instead.

```
SELECT dt.some_data, dt.date_visit, dt.url, 
      (SELECT date_visit FROM device_tracker 
       WHERE type_dev = dt.type_dev ORDER BY date_visit DESC LIMIT 1) last_visit,
      (SELECT date_visit FROM device_tracker 
       WHERE type_dev = dt.type_dev and url = dt.url ORDER BY date_visit DESC LIMIT 1) last_visit_to_this_url 
   FROM device_tracker dt WHERE some_where_clauses;
```

Please note that I don't need global max values (it could be really easy), but for example in this case I'm getting the max date of every single type_dev (every row can be a different type or not) and also the max date of a certain url regarding each row.

I Need the same with the minimun dates.

For sure there are a lot of nicer ways to do it. Could anyone throw some light on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    (
        SELECT  type_dev, MAX(date_visit) AS maxt, MIN(date_visit) AS mint
        FROM    device_tracker
        GROUP BY
                type_dev
        ) t
JOIN    (
        SELECT  type_dev, url, MAX(date_visit) AS maxtu, MIN(date_visit) AS mintu
        FROM    device_tracker
        GROUP BY
                type_dev, url
        ) tu
ON      tu.type_dev = t.type_dev
JOIN    device_tracker dt
ON      dt.type_dev = tu.type_dev
        AND dt.url = tu.url
```

Create a composite index on `(type_dev, url, date_visit)` for this to work fast.

Comment: This is amazing. Worked like a charm. Even without composite index, it was much much faster. Thank you!

Comment: @Javier: try to add a composite index, see the difference.

Comment: I already did it actually, I meant that with your solution I saw a huge diference even before setting the index. After setting it is even a little better. Thanks!